# Image under navabar

Tags: html, css

I currently have a navbar as such:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

And the following image at the bottom of the container:

```
    <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/test.png" alt="">
<!-- End of container -->
```

However the image underneath overlaps the text. How can I style the image such that it "pushes" everything on the page down so that it doesn't overlap any text (the same way a navbar behaves)

Comment: Please add your working code here.

Comment: Presumably, this is with Bootstrap? You need to provide more HTML to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>, and then at the very end of the container right before my /nav

Comment: I added an answer but please create a snippet or JS fiddle reproducing this problem if you need more specific help with this.

Answer (score 0):

A crude solution would be to add a line break with the `<br/>` tag. This method would separate the image from the navbar. Another solution would be to place a spacer tag between the two. This can be done by adjusting the height of a `<div>` tag.

While you certainly don't have to, I use an API that allows me to assign a class name of

`spacer(height of spacer in pixels)`

Or, for example, if I wanted a height of 250 pixels,

`spacer250`

while the API changes the height of the tag on the call of function

`$scs.createSpacers('div');`

If you would like to use the API, the library is found at [this link](https://smittycraft.github.io/apis/spacers.js).

Answer (score 0):

its simple, just provide a width and height to image. If this is what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="container">
 <h2>Image</h2>
  <p>The .img-responsive class makes the image scale nicely to the parent 
element (resize the browser window to see the effect):</p>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" 
 height="345"> 
 sdadsada
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That still doesnt push the page contents down though. Underneith the image i have this: And the "Abuse" header ends up being covered up, ideally, if I add an image with a width of x, the page contents would shift down by x aswell

Comment: Please add a fiddle for any more help

Answer (score 0):

You could place your image outside of your navbar if it isn't already. Otherwise you can add `display: block` to your image to push it to its own line. Further you can use margins or positioning to align it correctly.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
ul {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 5.65rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iyzGnF9.jpg">
```